# c++ ERROR libxml++ no such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu

HI,

I have the following: `#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>` and when i compile it says `fatal error: libxml++/libxml++.h.No such file or directory`. I've checked in the directory: /usr/include/libxml++-2.6/libxml++ and there it is the libxml++.h. Where am I wrong? why do i receive this error? thx

EDIT:

I did include g++ prg.cpp -o prg -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6/ and now i have the

```
error:fatal error: glibmm/ustring.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have `-I /usr/include/libxml++-2.6` in your g++ command line ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use pkg-config to get the correct compiler options. See, for instance:
http://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/stable/

Comment: and...what should I do if I use cmake? Copy-paste the whole output of ´pkg-config´?

Comment: I believe people use FindPkgConfig with CMake, though my past attempts have been fairly unconvincing: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/FindPkgConfig.html . Here is a a recent question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake

Answer (score 0):

Add the following option in the makefile:

```
g++ <some options> -I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6 <some other options>
```

The `-I` flag in `g++` adds the directory appearing after it to the `include path`. If you do not want to use that option, you need to replace the `#include<libxml++-2.6/libxml++.h>` with `#include "absolute path to above header file"`. Note that using the `-I` flag also allows you to replace `" "` after the `#include` with `< >` tags.

Answer (score -1):

add `-I/usr/include/libxml++-2.6/libxml++`  when compiling.

Comment: I did include what your link in my code (i didnt had to include libxml++) but now i have the error:  fatal error: glibmm/ustring.h: No such file or directory