# What is the proper way to use `pkg-config` from `cmake`?

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

I have seen a lot of code like this:

```cmake
include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_search_module(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)

target_include_directories(app SYSTEM PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(app ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

However, that seems to be the wrong way about doing it, as it only uses the include directories and libraries, but ignores defines, library paths and other flags that might be returned by `pkg-config`.

What would be the correct way to do this and ensure that all compile and link flags returned by `pkg-config` are used by the compiled `app`? And is there a single command to accomplish this, i.e., something like `target_use(app SDL2)`?

ref:

- [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html)
- [`FindPkgConfig`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you're using cmake and pkg-config in a pretty normal way, this solution works.

If, however, you have a library that exists in some development directory (such as `/home/me/hack/lib`), then using other methods seen here fail to configure the linker paths. Libraries that are not found under the typical install locations would result in linker errors, like `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmy-hacking-library-1.0`. This solution fixes the linker error for that case.

Another issue could be that the pkg-config files are not installed in the normal place, and the pkg-config paths for the project need to be added using the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable while cmake is running (see other Stack Overflow questions regarding this). This solution also works well when you use the correct pkg-config path.

Using `IMPORTED_TARGET` is key to solving the issues above. This solution is an improvement on [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443204/) and boils down to this final version of a working CMakeLists.txt:

```make
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ya-project C)

# the `pkg_check_modules` function is created with this call
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED) 

# these calls create special `PkgConfig::<MODULE>` variables
pkg_check_modules(MY_PKG REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET any-package)
pkg_check_modules(YOUR_PKG REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET ya-package)

add_executable(program-name file.c ya.c)

target_link_libraries(program-name PUBLIC
        PkgConfig::MY_PKG
        PkgConfig::YOUR_PKG)
```

Note that `target_link_libraries` does more than change the linker commands. It also propagates other PUBLIC properties of specified targets like compiler flags, compiler defines, include paths, etc., so, use the PUBLIC keyword with caution.

Comment: `IMPORTED_TARGET` requires CMake 3.6 or newer.

Comment: I think this failed for me because of https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19387.

Answer (score 97):

First off, the call:

```cmake
include(FindPkgConfig)
```

should be replaced with:

```cmake
find_package(PkgConfig)
```

The `find_package()` call is more flexible and allows options, such as `REQUIRED`, that do things automatically that one would have to do manually with `include()`.

Secondly, manually calling `pkg-config` should be avoided when possible. CMake comes with a rich set of package definitions, found on Linux under `/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/Find*cmake`. These provide more options and choice for the user than a raw call to `pkg_search_module()`.

As for the mentioned hypothetical `target_use()` command, CMake already has that built-in in a way with PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE. A call like `target_include_directories(mytarget PUBLIC ...)` will cause the include directories to be automatically used in every target that uses  `mytarget`, e.g., `target_link_libraries(myapp mytarget)`.

However, this mechanism seems to be only for libraries created within the `CMakeLists.txt` file and does not work for libraries acquired with `pkg_search_module()`. The call `add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)` might be used for that, but I haven't yet looked into that.

As for the main question, this here works in most cases:

```cmake
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
...
target_link_libraries(testapp ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(testapp PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(testapp PUBLIC ${SDL2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

The `SDL2_CFLAGS_OTHER` contains defines and other flags necessary for a successful compile. The flags `SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS` and `SDL2_LDFLAGS_OTHER` are however still ignored, no idea how often that would become a problem.

More documentation here: [CMake Documentation — FindPkgConfig](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html).

Comment: I agree that pkg-config should be avoided _IF_ a Find\*.cmake exists, but that still isn't the case for the latest version of cmake in 2016.

Comment: This does not work if the libraries are not in the default directories. link_directories() can be a workaround, but it is global.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for *vcpkg*. Can I locate SDL2_image without hard-coding paths!?

Comment: @HenryHu could you show how this would be done if this was the situation in the configuration in this answer?

Comment: Requiring a build tool like CMake to bundle heuristics to snif every library in the world makes no sense, it's not its role. Pkg-config is designed so that it's the responsibility of the lib author or the pkg/distro maintainer to make it available to the users. And if this scheme is followed, the correct way to use a lib is always through calling pkg-config.

Comment: since FindPkgConfig is a cmake builtin module (like CTest) using `include(FindPkgConfig)` is the way to go IMHO (since include search first in the cmake builtin module directory first).
see CTest documentation page: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html which use `include()`

Comment: BTW `include()` also have the `OPTIONAL` options....
src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment, I show rectify something: it's not CMake that bring all those files but the library authors. However, pkg-config is still a concept since the library author doesn't have to know or require what build system their users will use.

Comment: While I would really recommend to use the IMPORTED_TARGET approach used in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224542/211520, if you really need to `target_link_libraries()` then please use `<XXX>_LINK_LIBRARIES` instead of just `<XXX>_LIBRARIES`: The former has the full, absolute paths and thus works for non-standard directories too; for example when cross-compiling.

Answer (score 15):

It's rare that one would only need to link with SDL2. The currently popular answer uses `pkg_search_module()` which checks for given modules and uses the first working one.

It is more likely that you want to link with SDL2 and SDL2_Mixer and SDL2_TTF, etc... `pkg_check_modules()` checks for all the given modules.

```
# sdl2 linking variables
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_mixer SDL2_image)

# your app
file(GLOB SRC "my_app/*.c")
add_executable(my_app ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(my_app ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(my_app PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(my_app PUBLIC ${SDL2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

Disclaimer: I would have simply commented on Grumbel's self answer if I had enough street creds with stackoverflow.

Comment: Globbing source files is bad practice and discouraged.

Comment: For me, `target_link_libraries(my_app ${SDL2_LINK_LIBRARIES})` worked better.

Comment: @liberforce globbing source files is *good* practice, it's CMake's fault if it's buggy.

Comment: @JohanBoulé: No it's not. You may have a developer add a bunch of files locally and have the stuff work on their computer, and not commiting all the files needed. Then they push their changes and it breaks for other people. Sure, this can be caught by some continuous integration, but this is only the most obvious problem. The [Meson build system chose to not implement file globing](http://mesonbuild.com/FAQ.html#why-cant-i-specify-target-files-with-a-wildcard), and [CMake developers explicitly discourage globbing](https://youtu.be/bsXLMQ6WgIk?t=930). Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @liberforce I've seen that argument already many times more than the actual problem it theorises on. Meson's against, build2's for. None will have it, like tab vs space.

Comment: @liberforce That my friend is what we call an XY Problem. Solution is a CI hook that build on every push and rejects pull request that do not build.

Comment: @jfh please read the links I provided. Meson developers explicitly say: `This can not be made both reliable and fast. By reliable we mean that if the user adds a new source file to the subdirectory, Meson should detect that and make it part of the build automatically.

One of the main requirements of Meson is that it must be fast. This means that a no-op build in a tree of 10 000 source files must take no more than a fraction of a second. This is only possible because Meson knows the exact list of files to check.`

Comment: @liberforce: Explicit or implicit, the build breaks either way if a file doesn't get checked in.  Using an explicit list just provides TWO ways to break a build instead of one. I cannot imagine what the performance advantage of stat()-ing 10,000 source files would be over opendir/readdir-ing 10,000 source files would be. And it's not as if most of us have 10,000 source files *OR* glob patterns like */*/*/*.cpp *OR* are going to glob build output directories.

Answer (score 14):

Most of the available answers fail to configure the headers for the `pkg-config` library. After meditating on the [Documentation for FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) I came up with a solution that provides those also:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)
if(NOT PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "pkg-config not found!" )
endif()
 
pkg_check_modules(<some-lib> REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET <some-lib>)
 
target_link_libraries(<my-target> PkgConfig::<some-lib>)
```

(*Substitute your target in place of `<my-target>` and whatever library in place of `<some-lib>`, accordingly.*)

The `IMPORTED_TARGET` option seems to be key and makes everything then available under the `PkgConfig::` namespace. This was all that was required and also all that *should* be required.

Comment: TIP: print cmake var after running `pkg_check_modules` to see the available  vars https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328525/1211174

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no such command as `target_use`. But I know several projects that have written such a command for their internal use. But every project want to pass additional flags or defines, thus it does not make sense to have it in general CMake. Another reason not to have it are C++ templated libraries like Eigen, there is no library but you only have a bunch of include files.
2. The described way is often correct. It might differ for some libraries, then you'll have to add `_LDFLAGS` or `_CFLAGS`. One more reason for not having `target_use`. If it does not work for you, ask a new question specific about SDL2 or whatever library you want use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add definitions from the library as well, the `add_definitions` instruction is there for that. Documentation can be found [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html), along with more ways to add compiler flags.

The following code snippet uses this instruction to add GTKGL to the project:

```
pkg_check_modules(GTKGL REQUIRED gtkglext-1.0)
include_directories(${GTKGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKGL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTKGL_CFLAGS_OTHER})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${GTKGL_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries([insert name of program] ${LIBS})
```

Comment: Don't use `include_directories` etc it will infect global scope! Use `target_include_directories` etc