# Include static libsimple2d.a using cmake

Tags: cmake

I have downloaded and built the simple2d library using make && make install on OSX 10.13.4.

I was able to get my program to compile and link using the command line `` g++ `simple2d --libs` main.cpp ``

However I cannot figure out how to get it to work with CMake I have added the line `target_link_libraries(Pacman /usr/local/lib/libsimple2d.a)` But I get an error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when trying to build

Comment: Instead of `simple2d --libs` you mean `pkg-config simple2d --libs`, don't you? If so, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake) about using pkg-config with CMake.

Comment: Yeah I looked at that article and am using pkg_serach_module.  However I still cannot get it to link correctly.

Comment: Then, show what have you tried and what **exact error** you got for that. Just "Undefined symbols" isn't a very descriptive.