# Undefined references when included GLIB in clion using cmake

Tags: c, cmake, clion, glib

I am trying to write a notification service for gnome but cmake keeps outputting undefined reference errors when building. I am using clion IDE and glib2.0 libraries and running on Fedora workstation 30.

What I have tried so far is searching lots of stack overflow threads and googling for hours.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file, which is copied from another StackOverflow thread, is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(gnome_notification C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GLIB glib-2.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

My main.c file is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
int main() {
    GApplication* application = g_application_new ("Test", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    GNotification* notification = g_notification_new("Test Title");
    g_notification_set_body(notification, "Test body");
    g_notification_set_priority(notification, G_NOTIFICATION_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
    g_application_send_notification(application, "Test Id", notification);
    return 0;
}
```

The build yields undefined reference error:

```
/home/xgao/bin/Clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/cmake-build-debug --target gnome_notification -- -j 4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/cmake-build-debug
[ 50%] Linking C executable gnome_notification
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/gnome_notification.dir/main.c.o: in function `main':
/home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/main.c:4: undefined reference to `g_application_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/main.c:5: undefined reference to `g_notification_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/main.c:6: undefined reference to `g_notification_set_body'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/main.c:7: undefined reference to `g_notification_set_priority'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xgao/Desktop/gnome_notification/main.c:8: undefined reference to `g_application_send_notification'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/gnome_notification.dir/build.make:84: gnome_notification] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/gnome_notification.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/gnome_notification.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:118: gnome_notification] Error 2
```

Comment: That is not a CMake error you posted, but a linker error. However, it likely caused by your CMake because the linker cannot find the definitions for these `g_notification_*` calls you are making.

Comment: You can try adding `message(STATUS ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})` to your CMakeLists to see if CMake found the libraries correctly. Also I suggest looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake), and consider using `find_package()` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the question post (as **text**), not linked as *image*. Please, [edit] your question post and copy paste the error message into it. After the pasting, you may format that message as a code.

Comment: I still get the same error. message(STATUS ${GLIB_LIBRARIES}) doesn't seem to tell me any more info except the same old undefined errors.

Comment: Try adding in your target_link_libraries ${GLIB _LDFLAGS}

Comment: Use VERBOSE=1 to see the actual compiler output

Comment: Verbose throw the same error as in clion. I tried just compiling using gcc, without the cmake and make files. It throws the same linkage error. I am thinking issue lies elsewhere. It is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like

```
pkg_check_modules(GLIB glib-2.0 gio-2.0 REQUIRED)
```

or additionally

```
pkg_check_modules(GIO gio-2.0 REQUIRED)
```

because `GNotification` is provided by `libgio`, which is a separate library from `libglib`, even though they both come from the same source tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gcc -o note `pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0` note.c
```