# CMake: library not found during make build

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, glib

I am trying to setup a workspace where I can try out the GLib tutorials. I am new to C programming as well as make builds.

I am getting the following error while running the `make` command.

```
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -S/Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world -B/Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world/CMakeFiles /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello.dir/depend
cd /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world && /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build
[ 50%] Linking C executable hello
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/hello.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/hello.dir/src/hello.c.o  -o hello  -lglib-2.0 -lintl
ld: library not found for -lglib-2.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [hello] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Following is my CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project (hello_world_project)
include_directories(include)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)

message(INFO "libs:" ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
message(INFO "includes:" ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")

#Create an executable
add_executable(hello ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(hello PUBLIC 
    ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(hello PUBLIC 
    ${GLIB_LIBRARIES}
)
```

My cmake command is completed successfully with the following log:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2")
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0'
--   Found glib-2.0, version 2.62.5
INFOlibs:glib-2.0intl
INFOincludes:/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.5/include/glib-2.0/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.5/lib/glib-2.0/include/usr/local/opt/gettext/include/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/foo/workspaces/personal/c/glib_tut/hello_world
```

Can somebody please guide me on fixing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you put GLib on your machine? Did you install it somehow? Was it already installed?

Comment: You forgot to specify directories where libraries are located: `link_directories(${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS})`. Note, that this call should be issued **before** `add_executable`. See also other answers to the duplicate question, e.g. [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224542/3440745) which uses IMPORTED targets.

Comment: @squareskittles I installed via homebrew

Comment: @Tsyvarev Doing what you told resolved the issue for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is compile time error for a `Static Library` that is cased by `Static Linker`

```
ld: library not found for -l<Library_name>
```

You can get the error `Library not found for` when you have not include a library path to the `Library Search Paths`

`ld` means `Static Linker` which can not find a location of the library. As a developer you should help the linker and point the `Library Search Paths`

```
Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Library Search Paths
```