# Using Gnu autotools library in CMake project

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, autotools

I want to ask you a little question. In a project based on gnu-autotools I can use use my library(libtest based on gnu autotools) with a construction `"pkg-config --cflags libtest"` for include directory.

But the project based on Cmake I must use *.cmake config files (Or construction `include_directories ("/usr/local/include/libtest")` but this is ugly in my opinion).

How can I write and add this *.cmake files in my library? Do you know any library where I can see example? Or where I can read about this?

Regards, max

Comment: CMake has a ready module for `pkg-config`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake. So simply use `pkg_check_modules` instead of `find_package`. (Some `FindXXX.cmake` scripts use `pkg_check_modules` by themselves).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you. this 3 line help me : 
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(libtest REQUIRED libtest)
include_directories (${libtest_INCLUDE_DIRS})