# Cannot link sndfile library to cmake project (MacOS)

Tags: c++, cmake, libsndfile

Currently I'm trying to make some spectogram generation for my uni project. I'm trying to build a static library where all the magic will work and just call it from the main() function.

This is my cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(demo)


find_package(SndFile REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(spectogram)
add_executable(demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (demo LINK_PUBLIC Spectrogram)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE SndFile::sndfile)
```

**I have installed libsndfile via homebrew**, but find_package() refuses to locate the lib and throws this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSndFile.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SndFile", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SndFile" with any
  of the following names:

    SndFileConfig.cmake
    sndfile-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SndFile" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SndFile_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "SndFile" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I`ve made some research and found out that libsndfile does not have any .cmake configs inside like other libs, that I can link easily (like OpenCV or spdlog). I would really appreciate any help to solve this horror.

Comment: It looks like [sndfile project](https://github.com/libsndfile/libsndfile) provides a file `sndfile.pc` for ``pkg-config``, so you could use CMake module `PkgConfig` for that project. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake) about using that CMake module.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev, it looks like pkg-config did helped. It found the package, however it somehow couldn't found sndfile.hh file, so I checked LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES and LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS variables and they were empty. I found thid [FindLibSndFile.cmake](https://github.com/neXyon/audaspace/blob/master/cmake/FindLibSndFile.cmake) and i included it in my cmake file and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of Tsyvarev, I figured out the solution. I used the pkg-config module and a custom [cmake file](https://github.com/neXyon/audaspace/blob/master/cmake/FindLibSndFile.cmake), I found on the web. I will include my final cmake in case someone else will need it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(demo)


# - Try to find libsndfile
# Once done, this will define
#
#  LIBSNDFILE_FOUND - system has libsndfile
#  LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS - the libsndfile include directories
#  LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES - link these to use libsndfile

# Use pkg-config to get hints about paths
find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)
if(PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    pkg_check_modules(LIBSNDFILE_PKGCONF sndfile)
endif(PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)

# Include dir
find_path(LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES sndfile.h
        PATHS ${LIBSNDFILE_PKGCONF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        )

# Library
find_library(LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY
        NAMES sndfile libsndfile-1
        PATHS ${LIBSNDFILE_PKGCONF_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        )

find_package(PackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(LibSndFile  DEFAULT_MSG  LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR)

if(LIBSNDFILE_FOUND)
    set(LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES ${LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY})
    set(LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif(LIBSNDFILE_FOUND)

mark_as_advanced(LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARY LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIR LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS)

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_search_module(SndFile REQUIRED sndfile)

include_directories(${LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(spectogram)
add_executable(demo main.cpp)

message(STATUS "sndfile include dirs path: ${LIBSNDFILE_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "sndfile libs path: ${LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES}")

target_link_libraries (demo LINK_PUBLIC Spectrogram)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE ${LIBSNDFILE_LIBRARIES})
```