# How to fix the error "Python.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c

I have a C file that I am trying to integrate Python into, but it returns this error "Python.h: No such file or directory". This is my file:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
int main(int argl, char **argv)
{

        return 0;
}
```

I also tried to use cmake, but it gives me the same error, this is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(Test)

add_executable(main main.c)

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main ${Python_LIBRARIES})
```

[Output picture from the exec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVafw.png)

Comment: Please update question to include the text output instead of an external image that will break and render the question less useful.  Text is also searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what operating system you are using.  Debian (and Ubuntu) ships that header file in:

```
$ apt-file search /Python.h|grep h$
libpython2.7-dbg: /usr/include/python2.7_d/Python.h
libpython2.7-dev: /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
libpython3.9-dbg: /usr/include/python3.9d/Python.h
libpython3.9-dev: /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h
...
```

and you would install that with:

```
$ sudo apt install libpython3.9-dev
```

You tagged this with c and not [cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake), so the answer that you now need to include that directory with `-I/usr/include/python3.9`.  On the Debian the best way to do that is using so you would include that as an argument to when compiling the file:

```
$ pkg-config -cflags python-3.9
-I/usr/include/python3.9 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.9
```