# How to use RtAudio as a CMake dependency

Tags: c++, cmake, rtaudio

I am trying to use [RtAudio](https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio) in my project.
I installed it by executing :

- `git clone ...`
- `cmake -B target -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/.local`
- `cmake --build target`
- `cmake --install target`

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags --libs rtaudio`

returns

`-pthread -I$HOME/.local/include/rtaudio -D__UNIX_JACK__ -D__LINUX_ALSA__ -D__LINUX_PULSE__ -D_REENTRANT -L$HOME/.local/lib -lrtaudio`

But when I'm using the following CMakeLists.txt file

```
project(test_rtaudio)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(RtAudio REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "RtAudio include dirs : " ${RtAudio_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "RtAudio lib dirs :" ${RtAudio_LIBS})

include_directories(${RtAudio_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${RtAudio_LIBS})
```

The `RtAudioConfig.cmake` is found but there is no INCLUDE_DIRS or LIBS

```
CMake Debug Log at $HOME/.local/share/rtaudio/RtAudioConfig.cmake:26 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for FindThreads.cmake:

  The file was found at

    /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindThreads.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  find_package considered the following paths for FindRtAudio.cmake:

    /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindRtAudio.cmake

  The file was not found.

    $HOME/.local/share/rtaudio/RtAudioConfig.cmake



-- RtAudio include dirs : 
-- RtAudio lib dirs :
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: $HOME/Documents/project/sandbox/rtaudio/target
```

CMake actually find `RtAudioConfig.cmake` while it is looking for `pthread` lib.

There is **no** error, but as there is no include or lib files, as soon as I am trying to compile my project :

`cmake --build target`

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/test_rtaudio.dir/main.o 
/usr/bin/c++   -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test_rtaudio.dir/main.o -MF CMakeFiles/test_rtaudio.dir/main.o.d -o CMakeFiles/test_rtaudio.dir/main.o -c $HOME/Documents/project/sandbox/rtaudio/main.cpp
$HOME/Documents/project/sandbox/rtaudio/main.cpp:47:10: erreur fatale: RtAudio.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
   47 | #include <RtAudio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

`RtAudio.h` is not found.

**NB :** I have already tried to install the lib at the default location and the same error occurs.

I am not a professional `CMake` user and I can't determine if there is a miss configuration in my project or a lack of configuration while building or installing RtAudio.

If somebody have a solution or any idea

Comment: If you just need this library for this project, it would be worth your time to look into a package manager like Conan or vcpkg. They can integrate with cmake and download/install the dependencies for you. My personal preference is vcpkg because I can bundle it in my project as a submodule.

Comment: @sweenish This is not the only dependency and I have to convince my coworkers to use some package manager 

Comment: @273K Code build when I use "classic" build command `g++ main.cpp \`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags --libs rtaudio\` -o main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `find_package(RtAudio)` actually creates the IMPORTED target `RtAudio::rtaudio`, so you could simply link with that target:

```
find_package(RtAudio REQUIRED)

...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} RtAudio::rtaudio)
```

Not sure why they don't mention that in their documentation.

---

Alternatively, it is possible to use `pkg-config` for extract properties of the package:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(RtAudio REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET rtaudio)

...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PkgConfig::RtAudio)
```

(More information about using pkg-config in CMake could be found in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake).

Comment: Thx you  !! Is that working for all CMake package (and so make my `include_directories(${PackageName_INCLUDE_DIRS})`/`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PackageName_LIBS})` obsolete) or is there some special configurations ? 

Comment: The call to `find_package(RtAudio)` doesn't create variables `PackageName_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `PackageName_LIBS` , so the commands which uses them are not needed. It is dependent on specific package, whether its `find_package` creates variables/targets and with which names.