# MinIO: Where is the header, client.h?

Tags: c++, cmake, minio

I use command as follows build minio-cpp. Refer to https://github.com/minio/minio-cpp

git clone https://github.com/minio/minio-cpp

cd minio-cpp

wget --quiet -O vcpkg-master.zip
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

unzip -qq vcpkg-master.zip

./vcpkg-master/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh

./vcpkg-master/vcpkg integrate install

cmake -B ./build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake

cmake --build ./build --config Debug

I got,

```
DownloadObject.cc:1:10: fatal error: client.h: No such file or directory

     #include "client.h"
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

SET(requiredlibs)
list(APPEND requiredlibs stdc++fs)
list(APPEND requiredlibs CURL::libcurl)
list(APPEND requiredlibs OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)

SET(S3_LIBS ${requiredlibs})

project(DownloadObject LANGUAGES CXX)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} "DownloadObject.cc")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} miniocpp ${S3_LIBS})
```

DownloadObject.cc

```
#include "client.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Create S3 base URL.
  minio::s3::BaseUrl base_url("minio-api-endpoint");

  // Create credential provider.
  minio::creds::StaticProvider provider(
      "##########", "####################");

  // Create S3 client.
  minio::s3::Client client(base_url, &provider);

  // Create download object arguments.
  minio::s3::DownloadObjectArgs args;
  args.bucket = "minio-bucket";
  args.object = "test.py";
  args.filename = "downloaed-test.py";

  // Call download object.
  minio::s3::DownloadObjectResponse resp = client.DownloadObject(args);

  // Handle response.
  if (resp) {
    std::cout << "test.py is successfully downloaded to my-object.csv"
              << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "unable to download object; " << resp.Error().String()
              << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
cmake -B ./build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/work-on-api/install-minio-cpp/minio-cpp/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

cmake --build ./build --config Debug

```
DownloadObject.cc:1:10: fatal error: client.h: No such file or directory

     #include "client.h"
```

Comment: How is vcpg connected to your project? I see no `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` setting, neither in the command line nor in the `CMakeLists.txt`. What is `requiredlibs` variable, which you use in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Who does set this variable?

Comment: I updated the command. I use, cmake -B ./build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake". I referenced this CMakelists.txt, https://github.com/minio/minio-cpp/blob/main/examples/CMakeLists.txt and this file, https://github.com/minio/minio-cpp/blob/main/examples/DownloadObject.cc. I try to compile DownloadObject.cc. Please tell me how to compile it.

Comment: The minio-cpp project installs file `miniocpp.pc`, so you may try to use pkg-config for consume the package (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake). As for `requiredlibs` variable, it is filled with several libraries in the [top-level CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/minio/minio-cpp/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt). It could be that your particular example doesn't need all these libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I do not clearly know what libraries I may need. I picked a few and updated CMakeLists.txt. I also use find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED). I read the URL you shared with me above PkgConfig. I do not fully understand and no clue how to use it. I still got, client.h not found. Please help.

Comment: If it is possible, can please share with me a working version of CMakelists.txt?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thank you for your comments. Your comments gave me clue. I figured out that use the top-level CMakeLists.txt solved the problem.