# CMakeLists.txt : I do not get any executable output

Tags: c++, cmake, pkg-config

I want to convert this command line compilation and building:

```
g++ tutorial01.cpp -o tutorial01 -std=c++17 -I /usr/local/include/webkitgtk-4.1/webkit2 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0)
```

into a CMake building:

With this CMakeLists.txt file :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(tutorial01 LANGUAGES CXX)

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0)

add_executable(tutorial01 tutorial01.cpp)

target_compile_options(tutorial01 PUBLIC ${webkit2gtk-4.1_CFLAGS_OTHER} ${gtk+-3.0_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_include_directories(tutorial01 PUBLIC ${webkit2gtk-4.1_INCLUDE_DIRS})



target_link_libraries(tutorial01 PUBLIC
    gtk+-3.0_LIBRARIES
    webkit2gtk-4.1_LIBRARIES
)
```

There are no errors, but I do not get the executable file `tutorial01` :

```
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ cmake -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'webkit2gtk-4.0'
--   Found webkit2gtk-4.0, version 2.42.3
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/tutorial_webkitgtk/build


raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk/build$ ls -lah
total 48K
drwxrwxr-x 3 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 20 16:00 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 20 16:01 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy  24K dic 20 16:00 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 6 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 20 16:00 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 1,6K dic 20 16:00 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 raphy raphy 5,3K dic 20 16:00 Makefile

raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ ls -lah
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x  3 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 20 16:01 .
drwxr-x--- 78 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 20 15:23 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 raphy raphy 4,0K dic 20 16:00 build
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy  609 dic 20 16:00 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 raphy raphy 1,7K dic 20 13:41 tutorial01.cpp
```

Update 1:

With:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(tutorial01 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(gtk gtk+-3.0)
pkg_check_modules(webkit2gtk webkit2gtk-4.0)

message( STATUS IncludeDir: ${webkit2gtk-4.1_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(tutorial01 tutorial01.cpp)

target_compile_options(tutorial01 PUBLIC ${webkit2gtk-4.1_CFLAGS_OTHER} ${gtk+-3.0_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_include_directories(tutorial01 PUBLIC ${webkit2gtk-4.1_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${gtk+-3.0_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(tutorial01 PUBLIC
    gtk+-3.0_LIBRARIES
    webkit2gtk-4.1_LIBRARIES
)
```

I get "fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory" error:
in the building phase:

```
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ cmake -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.24.33
-- Checking for module 'webkit2gtk-4.0'
--   Found webkit2gtk-4.0, version 2.42.3
-- IncludeDir:
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/tutorial_webkitgtk/build
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ 
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ cmake --build build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/tutorial01.cpp.o
/home/raphy/tutorial_webkitgtk/tutorial01.cpp:3:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/tutorial01.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Update 2)

Thanks to all the people who commented, I reached the solution.

With this CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(tutorial01 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(gtk REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtk+-3.0)
pkg_check_modules(webkit2gtk REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET webkit2gtk-4.0)

add_executable(tutorial01 tutorial01.cpp)

target_compile_options(tutorial01 PUBLIC ${webkit2gtk_CFLAGS_OTHER} ${gtk_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_include_directories(tutorial01 PUBLIC ${webkit2gtk_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${gtk_INCLUDE_DIRS})


target_link_libraries(tutorial01 PUBLIC
    PkgConfig::gtk
    PkgConfig::webkit2gtk
)
```

I get the correct compilation and building:

```
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ cmake -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.24.33
-- Checking for module 'webkit2gtk-4.0'
--   Found webkit2gtk-4.0, version 2.42.3
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/tutorial_webkitgtk/build
 
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ cmake --build build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/tutorial01.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable tutorial01
[100%] Built target tutorial01
raphy@raohy:~/tutorial_webkitgtk$ ./build/tutorial01
```

Comment: You are not supposed to get executable output. CMake generates a makefile or project file for your compiler (or IDE) which then you need to build using your compiler or make. In your case the output from CMake is the Makefile in the build folder. You need to use the make utility to build your code.

Comment: @drescherjm
Yes. You are right. But when I execute make inside the /build subfolder , I get fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe you need dev package of gtk+ to get the headers.

Comment: @drescherjm This command-line compilation and building works fine :  g++ tutorial01.cpp -o tutorial01 -std=c++17 -I /usr/local/include/webkitgtk-4.1/webkit2 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0)

Comment: I removed my comment I believe the problem is in the versions but I am not qualified to answer pkg-config questions. My primary CMake usage is Visual Studio for the last 15+ years.

Comment: @drescherjm in CMakeLists.txt file I've set gtk+-3.0 for include_directories, compile_options and link_libraries. Now I get this error:  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/tutorial01.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable tutorial01
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk+-3.0_LIBRARIES: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebkit2gtk-4.1_LIBRARIES: No such file or directory

Comment: Does adding `message( STATUS IncludeDir: ${webkit2gtk-4.1_INCLUDE_DIRS})` to the CMakeLists.txt after `pkg_check_modules(gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0)` cause it to print anything after the `IncudeDir:`

Comment: @drescherjm I added that message. The make output is : build$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/tutorial01.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable tutorial01
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk+-3.0_LIBRARIES: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebkit2gtk-4.1_LIBRARIES: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/build.make:97: tutorial01] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/tutorial01.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

Comment: You would have to run `cmake .`  from the build folder to see the output I was looking for.

Comment: @drescherjm : build$ cmake .
-- IncludeDir:
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/tutorial_webkitgtk/build
I found a log: /build/CMakeFiles/CmakeConfigureLog.yaml . I've put into a text file and uploaded in a google drive : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qB61JbKj-Dl-7nncuwRWMgFzzmfrdXM9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this means the versions of webkit2gtk are at least part the problem. `Found webkit2gtk-4.0, version 2.42.3`  and `pkg_check_modules(gtk+-3.0 webkit2gtk-4.0)` and `${webkit2gtk-4.1_INCLUDE_DIRS}`

Comment: The **first parameter** to the `pkg_check_modules` denotes the prefix of variables/targets which will be created by CMake for reflect properties of the package. Usage of those variables/targets is described in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191855/what-is-the-proper-way-to-use-pkg-config-from-cmake) and its answers. Make sure to carefully read them. If you want to search several packages, then call `pkg_check_modules` **several times**, each time with distinct first parameter. E.g. `pkg_check_modules(GTK gtk+-3.0)`, `pkg_check_modules(WEBKIT2GTK webkit2gtk-4.0)`

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated my question above with Update 1) : I get "fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory"  with : pkg_check_modules(gtk gtk+-3.0)

Comment: Please, re-read my previous comment carefully. In the call `pkg_check_modules(webkit2gtk webkit2gtk-4.0)` the names of created variables are based on the **first parameter** (`webkit2gtk`), not on the second one (`webkit2gtk-4.0`). So, the variables are `webkit2gtk_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `webkit2gtk_LIBRARIES` and so one. Not the ones you use in your current code.